# Is it possible to render html containing {{binding}} using [innerHTML]

Tags: angular, rendering, innerhtml

Let say I have a string like this

```
html = "<p>Hello <b>{{name}}</b></p>"
```

Is it possible to extrapolate {{name}} while using it in [innerHTML]

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">

<div [innerHTML]="html | safeHtml"></div>
```

so the name would bind inside innerHTML ?

PS: My html is actualy an email template I'm receiving from my backend, so I cannot really put my html inside my component.html if I want to include binding.

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks to access `variable` in string concatenation like this,

```
html = `<p>Hello <b> ${name}</b></p>`
```